# Jsonwebtoken library with vueJS issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, jwt

In order to create jwt, I installed jsonwebtoken library and imported it in my project as below:

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
```

Then I created a function to create the token:

```
function createJwt(){    
var token = jwt.sign(data, private_key, {
    algorithm: "RS256"
  });
  console.log(token);
}
```

Note: data, private_key are already defined in my application.

Using this code gives me this error:

```
fixProc.js?4dd0:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
at module.exports (fixProc.js?4dd0:14)
at parseKeys (index.js?2aee:19)
at sign (sign.js?6fe7:10)
at Sign.signMethod [as sign] (index.js?b692:41)
at Object.sign (index.js?79e8:152)
at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (sign-stream.js?6c3c:32)
at Object.module.exports [as sign] (sign.js?2567:204)
at createToken (state.js?fcc2:70)
at eval (state.js?fcc2:76)
at Module../src/store/state.js (app.js:1798)
```

I also tried with crypto library from nodejs but the result is the same. May the problem comes from my import ?

I would really appreciate advice and best practice to generate JWT.

Regards,
Jacky

Comment: Are you creating these tokens client-side, or in a node.js back-end?

Comment: That error means your private key value is likely wrong/in the wrong format.

Comment: I was trying to create the token from client-side script.

Comment: And the private key was had this format : private_key:
    "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----xxxxxxxx-----END PRIVATE KEY-----",